# How to instantiate a parameterized type class by name

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, parameterization

Following Example:

I have a service that can 'start' any vehicle

```
interface VehicleStarterService<T: Vehicle> {
   fun <T : Vehicle> start(vehicle: Class<T>): String {
       return vehicle.start
   }
}
```

I would like to start a vehicle type by name like "Car", which would require me to create a VehicleStarterService; however I cannot seem to find a way to instantiate an interface with a class that is instantiated by name.

I would like to do something like (but cannot):

```
val cls = "Car"
val kClass = Class.forName(cls).kotlin
val service = VehicleStarterService<kClass>()
service.start
```

I end up having to do the following (creating a service for every paramaterized type I need):

```
class CarStarterService : VehicleStarterService<Car> {
    fun <T> execute() : String {
        return start(User::class.java)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to instantiate a paramaterized class in this way?

Comment: I would say no. Type instantiation must happen at compile time but the type name in a string is only known at run time. Depending on what `start` should really do, maybe generics are not necessary and a common interface for all vehicles plus a class object for the particular vehicle are enough.

Comment: What you're going to do is equivalent to a raw type, so just use the raw type.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if this would be sufficient for your situation, but perhaps you could just match the class based on the string like this

```
val cls = "Car"
val service: VehicleStarterService<out Vehicle>? = when (cls) {
    "Car"  -> object : VehicleStarterService<Car> {}
    "Boat" -> object : VehicleStarterService<Boat> {}
    "Plane" -> object : VehicleStarterService<Plane> {}
    else   -> null
}
service?.start(...
```

EDIT: hashmap registry idea to allow some extensibility..

```
val serviceRegistry = HashMap<String, VehicleStarterService<out Vehicle>>()
    .apply {
        //default services
        this["Car"] = object : VehicleStarterService<Car> {}
        this["Boat"] = object: VehicleStarterService<Boat> {}
    }
.
.
.
//Adding entry
serviceRegistry["Plane"] = object: VehicleStarterService<Plane> {}
.
.
.
//Fetching entry
val cls = "Car"
val service = serviceRegistry[cls]

service?.start(...
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to avoid adding a matcher like that (requiring someone else to change an underlying 'library' class) but yes, that's definitely an option!

Comment: I edited in a second idea, using a hashmap as a registry so that someone else could add their own services and fetch those as well

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see your problem. Note that the generic type information is erased at runtime (at least for the JVM-variant which you are obviously using). So it basically doesn't matter which generically typed service you use.
You can also just use `VehicleStarterService<Vehicle>` and it will start all your vehicles. If for any reason you need to call a specific (other!) function you still need to check/cast to your actual type... So I see no benefit in trying to get that generic typed interface.

Having said that there are still methods to do it... (note again: it doesn't really matter... generic type information is erased at runtime...)

Now for my tests I use this entry method:

```
fun startAllTheVehicles(vararg vehicleTypes: String) {
  startAllTheVehicles(*vehicleTypes.map { Class.forName(it) }
                                   .map { it as Class<out Vehicle> }
                                   .toTypedArray())
}
```

Note that `it as Class<out Vehicle>` is NOT ensuring that you have a class of type `Vehicle`. It just makes sure that your code compiles when trying to call your functions that declare `Class<out Vehicle>` as a parameter type.

So starting from there you could use one of the following ways to have an actual generic type available. I am assuming you use something like `newInstance` within your start service.

1. Sample with the generic type omitted on the interface (that case is rather easy):

   ```
   interface VehicleStarterService {
     fun <T: Vehicle> start(vehicleType: Class<T>) = vehicleType.newInstance().start
   }
   ```

   Sample method that is called by the above entry function using one service to start all vehicles:

   ```
   fun <T : Vehicle> startAllTheVehicles(vararg vehicleTypes: Class<out T>) {
     val service = object : VehicleStarterService {}
     vehicleTypes.forEach { service.start(it) }
   }
   ```
2. Still using an interface with generic type (note the changes regarding `out T`, etc.):

   ```
   interface VehicleStarterService<T: Vehicle> {
     fun start(vehicleType: Class<out T>) = vehicleType.newInstance().start
   }
   ```

   Sample method that is called by the entry function using one service to start all vehicles:

   ```
   fun <T : Vehicle> startAllTheVehicles(vararg vehicleTypes: Class<out T>) {
     // actually it doesn't really matter which type we use...
     val service = object : VehicleStarterService<Vehicle> {} // you could even use T instead of Vehicle
     vehicleTypes.forEach { service.start(it) }
   }
   ```

Testing both with the following works as expected:

```
startAllTheVehicles("Car", "Truck")
```

Calling it with a type that is actually no `Vehicle` will give you a `ClassCastException` at the interface's `start`-function.